# Select SQL Query on Controller - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

What I'm trying to do is a report bringing values of a table, but just if this table have specific selected client and others specific properties

Activation Report, follow a part of the code that already is working

```
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM ativacao WHERE id_cliente = " + id_cliente;

var itemAtivacao = db.ativacao.SqlQuery(sql).ToList();

foreach (var item in itemAtivacao)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(item.id, item.codigo, item.cliente.nome);
}
```

Until here Ok, easy. but I need to bring elements of table cliente, of other table comparing with a column. Damnt, it is boring.

Apart from the specifit client, I need to:

```
 var id_executivo = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["id_executivo"]);

 var id_prospector = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["id_prospector"]);

 var id_cluster = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["id_cluster"]); 

 var id_status = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["id_status"]);

 var id_cliente = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["id_cliente"]);
```

This is Columns of table Client. I'm thinking about INNER JOIN. is it???

summing up - I need to bring ativacoes of specific cliente if this cliente contains ......

Someone help me how can I do it please. Thanks so much.

Comment: This is a very poorly designed question. Please, see how to [Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes you want an inner join between ativacao and client with the where clause hitting the client table instead of the ativacao table.
Also please parameterize the sql query, dynamic sql is bad unless absolutely needed, then its still bad.